# Truly private JavaScript class members (ES6)

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, ecmascript-6

I've found pretty simple and clear pattern which can be used to make any data members truly private (invisible, inaccessible) without affecting class behavior (no prototypes and `Object.XXX` magics required).

This **"Lock & Key"** pattern uses closures with ES6 `Symbol`'s and Proxy approaches:

```
const MyClass = (()=>{

    const _PRIVATE_STORAGE = Symbol('PRIVATE_STORAGE'); // visible, see below
    const _PRIVATE_KEY     = Symbol('PRIVATE_KEY');     // fully hidden

    function privateFun(newValue) {
        const _this = this[_PRIVATE_STORAGE](_PRIVATE_KEY);
        _this.private_value = newValue;
        console.log('changed: private_value = ' + _this.private_value);
    }

    class MyClass {
        constructor() {
            // Truly private data
            const _this = {};

            // "Lock" closure function (!)
            this[_PRIVATE_STORAGE] = (key) => (
                key === _PRIVATE_KEY ? _this : undefined);

            // Any initialization
            _this.private_value = 0;
        }

        publicFun1() {
            const _this = this[_PRIVATE_STORAGE](_PRIVATE_KEY);
            console.log('private_value = ' + _this.private_value);
        }

        publicFun2(newValue) {
            return privateFun.call(this, newValue);
        }
    }

    return MyClass;

})();

const obj = new MyClass;
obj.publicFun1();
obj.publicFun2(42);
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj));
console.log(obj[Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj)[0]]);
console.log(obj[Symbol('PRIVATE_KEY')]);
```

Output:

```
private_value = 0
changed: private_value = 42
[]
[ Symbol(PRIVATE_STORAGE) ]
[Function]
undefined
```

**Pros**:

- No memory overhead, no `WeakMap`'s.
- Private properties are truly inaccessible and innumerable (except for one `Symbol`).
- Private methods are truly hidden (well known approach with `call` invocation).
- "Class" is just a standard JavaScript function: any kind of inheritance, prototype extension, mixins, decorators etc. are supported.

**Cons**:

- +2 indirection levels (in comparison with simplest "name conventions" approach), so +2 function calls overhead.

Thank you in advance for review, I'm looking for any suggestions/critique thoughts and maybe additional pros-cons points and underwater rocks.

*In addition*: I didn't find any completely identical approach mentioned in the web, so it may be a known technique. Otherwise, I've found it a very interesting and useful task to investigate and implement.

Comment: Cons? Don't you mean 4 function calls... `obj.publicFun2(` calls `privateFun.cal(`l which calls `privateFun(` which calls `this[__PRIVATE_STORAGE](` And Pros? *"Class... just a... function"* , then why not just use closure and standard object invocation?

Comment: Every once in a while, a "private members in JS" question comes along. Sometimes I wonder why people keep forcing JavaScript to do things it wasn't designed to do.

Comment: The sugar coated class madness drives JS to the ridiculous. What's  ESnext... a proposal to include private fields, `class foo { #privateField = "blah"; constructor ()( this.#privateField += " blah"; this.#notPrivate = 0; )}` Wow this cant be real can it? the variable name includes the usage as a prefix, well if you put it in the right spot that is, oh and its a field, cannot assign a function to it.  I  wish `class` would go away :(